# Shiny's tabsetPanel not displaying plots in multiple tabs

Tags: r, tabs, plot, shiny

I am trying to use multiple `tabPanel` controls within the `tabsetPanel` in `Shiny`. Lets say I start with only one tab using the following code:

```
mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("distPlot"))
    )
```

The code runs fine and displays the plot in the tab.

But the moment I introduce another tab just to test the tabs out, both the tabs stop displaying any plots at all. I am using the following code:

```
mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("distPlot")),
    tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("distPlot"))
    )
```

Please note that I am trying to display the same plot in both tabs just to test if the tabs work. All I get are two blank tabs (if I use only one tab, the plot displays properly).

Would someone please be able to help me figure this out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You assign `"distPlot"` to `plotOutput`'s parameter `outputId`. "ID" indicates that this value has to be unique over the entire shiny app. You can assign the same plot to two different `plotOutput`s though:

```
runApp( list(

  server = function(input, output) {
    df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10) )
    output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({ plot( df, x ~ y ) })
    output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({ plot( df, x ~ y ) })
  },

  ui = fluidPage( mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel( "Plot", plotOutput("distPlot1") ),
      tabPanel( "Plot", plotOutput("distPlot2") )
    )
  ))
))
```

Comment: That makes complete sense. Worked perfectly. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

we can also write the above code in a single line as

```
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel( "Plot", plotOutput("distPlot1"),plotOutput("distPlot2") )
)
```